# How do I manage open datagram sockets to avoid exceeding maximum?

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

I'm developing some code that uses a large number of datagram sockets.  Without careful coding, this number can exceed the maximum allowed by the jvm.  Using `-Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets=x` isn't always an option.  I have code something like this:

```
/* opening this channel will bring us to the limit--the maximum allowed by the JVM */
DatagramChannel channel1 = DatagramChannel.open();

/* do some stuff with channel1 */

/* Close channel1, and dereference it */
channel1.close();
channel1 = null;

/* this throws SocketException */
DatagramChannel channel2 = DatagramChannel.open();
```

Sharing `DatagramChannel`s (i.e., using `receive()`) might be another option, but knowing what's going on here would be useful.

EDIT: After a bit more work narrowing down the problem in the real code, I found that the code snippet was too simplified.  The idea here was that after the maximum number of `DatagramChannel`s had been reached, a new one would only be created when another had been closed.  However, I was dealing with a mixture of `SocketChannel`s and `DatagramChannel`s, and the problem was that even though I was calling `close()` on the channels as I was done with them, I had to make sure the channel I had just closed was a `DatagramChannel` (rather than a `SocketChannel`) before creating another.  Just an oversight.

Comment: Have you looked at `AutoCloseable` and `[try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)`? But I cannot understand why `channel2` in the above should throw exception if ``channel1` has been closed...

Comment: Thanks.  `DatagramChannel` implements `Closeable`, and `try-with-resources` simply ensures that `close()` is called on the resource before the `try` block finishes (i.e., what `finally` would do).  As far as I can tell, the code in the question is the same as what those would offer.

Comment: Right, so why would `channel2 = DatagramChannel.open()` would throw exception if `channel1.close()` was successful?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to know :).  I don't know if it's because of garbage collection delay or something else, and what might be recommended to work around it.

Comment: Garbage collection is unrelated. On that topic, even `channel1 = null` is not needed. I suspect the problem is elsewhere. Ira's suggestion below may be useful. Or else I would wrap the  `DatagramChannel` in another class where I log there open and close. I suspect you are not closing them. Please update the question with the exception output.

Comment: Why? You only need one UDP socket.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to use a set of pooled sockets that can be reused. I would recommend using a framework such as [netty](http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html) to avoid having to implement all of the nitty gritty details yourself.